# See the type of a var in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, var

Is there a way to see the type of a `var` within the Visual Studio 2013 code editor?

When I have a crazy `linq` query it would be nice to see what the resulting type will be.  I don't want to replace the `var` keyword with the actual type, I just want to see what it is.

Comment: by hovering on particular var??

Comment: In some versions, mouseover the var keyword will not show anything, but in 2013 it should show the Type. You can also mouseover the variable itself.

Comment: [How to: Use Debugger Variable Windows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bhawk8xd.aspx)

Comment: @TimSchmelter - Not sure if your link applies.  I want to see the type during design time.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can get it by Hovering on particular var keyword.

For example see in below image the tooltip shows the details.

[image]

Comment: Does anyone know how to get this to work while debugging? When debugging I can't hover over fields/methods to see their descriptions, but CTRL-K, I works when debugging.

Answer (score 18):

There is also a keyboard shortcut that will show you.  Put the cursor over `var` and type:

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd>, <kbd>i</kbd>

[image]

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Great ...but how did u come to know this ?

Comment: Don't recall exactly where I found it, possibly from digging through the VS Keyboard mappings

Answer (score 12):

For newer versions of VS (I'm not sure this applies to 2013), you have the option to go down to:

`Tools > Options > Text Editor > C# > Advanced`

Scroll down to the "Inline Hints' section and enable `Display inline type hints` to show type hints inline with the line where the `var` is specified. There's also an option to display parameter name hints there, also very useful.

Answer (score 5):

[image]
For Vs 2019 or 2022
Go to visual studio **Option > Text Editor > c# > Advanced > Display inline type hints**

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Hover your mouse over the `var` keyword, it will show it in a tooltip.

Comment: You can also use F12 to go to definition on the `var` keyword, and it'll take you to the class.

Comment: Will it do this for the result of a `linq` query?

Comment: Yes, the compiler can still infer the type from a linq query - unless you select an anonymous type, I'm not sure what it does then.

Answer (score 2):

Hover on the variable... It will tell you.

Comment: _variable_? or `var` keyword?

Comment: Both will work. On the Var keyword, it will tell you the Type var replace, on the variable, it will let you explore it as a usual variable (including the type).

Answer (score 2):

The text of the type can often be obtained (using copy and paste) by temporarily changing the `var` to an explicit type, say `int`. That will force a compilation error. After doing a **Build solution** the type of the variable should be written in both the **Error list** and the **Output** panes.

Answer (score 1):

Move your mouse cursor hover the `var` keyword, a tooltip will show you the actual type.

Answer (score 0):

Add a variable watch. Check the type in the watch window.