# How do I disable the variable type hint for a 'var' declared variable in Rider?

Tags: c#, rider

In Jetbrains Rider the type of a 'var' declared variable is shown as hint by default. I don't want that. How can I get rid of it?

[image]

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/rider/Inline_Parameter_Name_Hints.html?

Comment: Now I want the same in my Visual Studio. [Hovering](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26137511/1997232) is not so cool.

Comment: @jonrsharpe When I disable all inlays, these hints remain. The inlays are for specific languages like Angular, JavaScript, SQL, but C# is not one of the listed languages there.

Comment: [*"Note that parameter name hints in C# and VB.NET are enabled/disabled and configured separately from hints in JavaScript, TypeScript, and SQL."*](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/rider/Inline_Parameter_Name_Hints.html#configuring-parameter-name-hints)

Comment: @jonrsharpe ah reading everything remains a challenge. Gotcha. Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Disable Parameter Name Hints as shown below:

[image: Disable Parameter Name Hints]

Answer (score 4):

In JetBrains Rider 2022.2, I found the checkbox `Enable Inlay Hints in .NET languages` under
**Settings --> Editor --> Inlay Hints**.

[image: Screenshot of the Settings dialog box in JetBrains Rider 2022.2, displaying the path Editor --> Inlay Hints --> checkbox 'Enable Inlay Hints in .NET languages']

That solved it for me.

Answer (score 1):

It is not in Inlay settings but under "Syntax Style".

[image]

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).